# Get unkown attribute from a specific XML node using VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

I need to retrieve the **attribute itself**, **NOT** the *attribute value*, from a specific node.

For example for Object 2, the attribute is "operation" *not* "update"and for Object3, the attribute is "name" *not* "A51". If I want to get the attribute value, I would use something like `node2.getAttribute("operation")` but **that's not what I want**

```
<Object1 class="second"/>
<Object2 operation="update"/>
<Object3 name="A51"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way. It's really simple, just add `.Attributes.Item(i).nodeName` to your node. `i` is just the attribute position. In my case it would be:

```
node1.Attributes.Item(0).nodeName
```